# Debye Model and Energy Expectation factors

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics

I know this sounds like a simple question but when calculating the expectation value of energy using the debye model, after some calculation it becomes $$\langle E\rangle=\int_{0}^{\infty}\hbar\omega(\langle n \rangle + \frac{1}{2})D(\omega)d\omega$$ where $D(\omega)$ is the density of states. My question is what does the factor of a half mean? I think I understand that $\hbar\omega$ is the energy of a phonon and $\langle n \rangle$ is the average number of phonons in one state so the product of them would result in the average energy in one state but I can't seem to understand what the half of a phonon energy entails physically? I hope this makes sense, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better not to write this $\frac{1}{2}$ in this formula, because integral with it will diverge.
This factor comes from quantum mechanical problem about oscillator. It reflects in it that oscillator cannot freeze absolutely because of Heisenberg's uncertainty principle and therefore it has some energy even in its ground state. 
Nevertheless, in solid state physics it only messes things up. The reason is that you calculate average amount of energy in a crystal and therefore it is more convenient just to drop out this, counting energy from another potential level. The only thing which depends on temperature in this formula is $\langle n \rangle$, therefore after dropping $\frac{1}{2}$ term you will not change the results for specific heat and another things of importance.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you very much Goro!